# regular expression for a street address php

Tags: php, regex, expression

I'm trying to write a regular expression for a street address. Example: `124 Street`
I'm not really sure how to go about this. So far I have something that looks like this
`^[0-9][a-zA-Z]$`.
However this is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Well you need to allow for the space, and for multiple characters - but even when you've done so what about addresses like `103/72 Some Street` or `Suite 103, 72 Some Street`?

Comment: Great point. This is only for a class so I only have to worry about an address like this at the moment 123 street

Comment: @mvmrocks we are able to tell you how to do the things you want, but we still need to know what you do want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^[0-9][a-zA-Z]$` will match a single digit followed by a single letter.

If you want to match any non-empty string consisting of only letters, digits, spaces and periods, use

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z. ]+$
```

If you want to match (a string of digits and a space) optional, followed by a string of letters and spaces, that would be

```
^([0-9]+ )?[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

Comment: I live at *qwdl3ld*.  That would be considered a valid address with this regex.

Comment: @Vulcan What do you suggest? No letters before digits? No letters around digits? You still need to allow letters after digits: `street of 1st of may`

Comment: If I remove the ? so it looks like this ^([0-9]+ )[a-zA-Z ]+$ it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for everyone who was able to help!

Comment: @JanDvorak - How about houses that are not numbered. My parents house does not have a number - It has a name.

Comment: @mvmrocks If you remove the `?` you will require the sequence of digits. In that case you could remove the second space as well.

Comment: @EdHeal note the digits sequence is optional

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new to this. @JanDvorak That worked, Thank you. For every one else who helped thank you too. It was for a class assignment and the only requirement were to have numbers then a street name. I know there are other address that need to be taken into account if this was an actual validation.

Comment: @mvmrocks it would be easier if you told us the requirement in advance ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is a better one

```
`'^((Flat [1-9][0-9]*, )?([1-9][0-9]* ))?([A-Z][a-z]* )*([A-Z][a-z]*)$'`
```

Comment: @JanDvorak - Was going to write a regex for addresses next week. Saved me sometime.

Comment: Note that this won't accept the `1st of May st.`, you could (and should) be more benevolent.

Comment: Who lives at that address "1st of May st." - oops - `1 May St, Rustavi, Kvemo Kartli, Georgia` according to Google maps. There you go, I am going to send a Christmas card. Please do the same